# AngularJS barcode not showing up in print page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right now, I am trying to implement a barcode generation based on an ID of a customer. I am using the [zhuk-aa/angular-barcode-generator](https://github.com/zhuk-aa/angular-barcode-generator) from GitHub to accomplish this, and it generates barcodes fine on my webpage. The problem is, it does not show the barcode on the print screen, which is the part that it 100% needs to be in. The documentation for the angular-barcode-generator is pretty low on how to use it, so if anyone could provide some clarification here on how to make it show up, that would be great!